# SQL how to reference a variable column

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, reference

I'm trying to create a wallpaper sharing gallery, and i want my visitors to be able to post comments on both wallpapers and articles.

Let's say i have the following tables :

```
Wallpaper
- id
- name
- etc...

Article
- id
- title
- etc...

Comment
- id
- text
```

I would like a comment to be associated to either a unique wallpaper or a unique article.

I've thought about making inheritance like this :

```
Commentable
- id

Article
- id references Commentable.id
- etc...

Wallpaper
- id references Commentable.id
- etc...

Comment
- id
- commented references commentable.id
```

But this method looks heavy and not really nice.

I've also thought about making :

```
Wallpaper
- id
- name
- etc...

Article
- id
- title
- etc...

Comment
- id
- commented references either Wallpaper.id or Article.id
```

But there would be no way to know if the associated thing is a wallpaper or an article.

Also i want to use MyISAM and not InnoDB as i'll upload this on a free web host service with a 5.1 MySQL.

Do you know any clear way of doing this please ? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Thanks to everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options for you:

**Option One**

```
Wallpaper
- id
- name

Article
- id
- title

Comment
- id
- wallpaper_id <== FK
- article_id   <== FK
```

Pros: Referential integrity
Cons: You have to modify schema to comment on additional entity types

**Option Two**

```
Wallpaper
- id
- name

Article
- id
- title

Comment
- id
- entity_id <== either a wallpaper id or article id
- entity_type <== one of 'wallpaper' or 'article' (use lookup table if you wish)
```

Pros: You don't have to modify schema to comment on additional entity types
Cons: No referential integrity (although could be enforced via trigger)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've thought about the first one, but that would leave 50% of NULL (and more if i had more than two tables to reference). What do you mean by "modify schéma to comment on" ?

Comment: @Virus721 Let's say you had a new table called Story you wanted users to comment on. With option 1, you would have to modify the schema to accomodate this. Not so with option 2. What is your concern with having `NULL` columns?

Comment: I can modify the schema as much as i want, it's not a problem. The fact of having many NULL values that could be avoided by using a "clearer" schema sounds not really nice. I guess I'll go for the 2nd choice.

Comment: Wait i've tought about another way !
What if I make the tables Wallpaper and Article  without any foreign key, and then make associations tables like : Wallpaper_Comment and Article_Comment, and use a UNIQUE index on Wallpaper_Comment.commentId and Article_Comment.commentId in order to make sure that a comment is only related to a single Article or Wallpaper ?

Comment: I have tried that approach before, but found it is a hassle when you want to retrieve comments from multiple entities, as you are querying multiple tables at this point. And of course, the tables will proliferate as you allow commenting on more entities. I prefer my options above.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for something as simple as adding a field to your Comment table named type, making it a Tinyint. Then when storing a comment, you either make that 0 or 1, choosing which is which type, so whether 0 is wallpaper of article.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding a type field to your Comment table. You could populate it with a string like 'ARTICLE' or 'WALLPAPER', or create a ref table. Something like:

```
Type_Ref
- id
- desc
```

Type_Ref would contain the auto incremented primary key, and a description of Wallpaper or Article.

Then in your comment table, you would just have a Type_Ref_Id field, with the corresponding id. Then, whenever you need to add a new Type to vote on, you can simply add an entry to the ref table.